# how to fix styles refresh on new page using nextjs?

Tags: css, next.js, sass, module

How to fix styles refresh on save without restarting the server?

Using Nextjs created a new page and imported styles module file. They work but when adding new styles, the styles do not show on the browser on save, only after restarting the dev server.

Tried to search but didn't find the answer.

Comment: Please read [ask] and add [mre]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Was able to find a solution by commenting out the imported styles, saving to refresh then uncomment styles and save/refresh.

Comment: import styles from "../styles/Banner.module.scss";

if styles do not apply then comment and save the uncomment the line of code. Proceed to save and browser refresh.